# Schwarzschild energy-momentum tensor

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, mass-energy, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

How can I figure out the components of the stress-energy tensor for an object i.e. a planet, star, black hole, etc. And especially what is the stress-energy tensor of a Schwarzschild-geometric gravitating body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the metric tensor, you can calculate the Ricci tensor and the Ricci scalar from their definition and plug them into Einstein's field equation to obtain the stress-energy tensor.

$T_{\mu\nu} = \frac{c^4}{8\pi G}(R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}Rg_{\mu\nu})$

In the case of Schwarzschild metric, it is a solution of the vacuum Einstein equation, therefore the stress-energy tensor is null everywhere the metric is defined (e.g. outside of the spherically symmetric massive body that generates the field).

**ADDENDUM:** if instead you don't know the metric, the problem is far more complicated. If you assume that:

- the body is spherically symmetric
- made of isotropic perfect fluid
- in hydrostatic equilibrium

then you have to solve the [Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolman%E2%80%93Oppenheimer%E2%80%93Volkoff_equation) equation.

If you know that in the equation of state the pressure depends only on the density (such as in a politropic gas), the solution is completely determined by:

- mass equation: $\frac{dm}{dr} = 4\pi r^2 \rho$
- Tolman–Oppenheimer–Volkoff equation
- equation of state $P=P(\rho)$

Once you solve this system of ODEs, you have the pressure and density profiles $P(r)$ and $\rho(r)$. You can then write the stress-energy tensor of the perfect fluid in the reference system in which the fluid is stationary as

$T^{\mu\nu} = diag(\rho,P,P,P)$

Unfortunately these assumptions do not always hold. They are good to describe compact degenerate objects like neutron stars, but are unfit to describe stars, where the pressure contribution provided by the energy released by the nuclear reactions is essential.

On the other hand, stars and planets can be very well described as non relativistic objects. A classical treatment could simplify things a bit, or complicate them enormously, depending on the level of detail you want to reach. See the [stellar structure equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_structure) for a taste of this fascinating subject.

A last word about Schwarzschild black holes, their stress-energy tensor is very simple. As already stated, it is null everywhere except in the singularity.

Answer (score 2):

The stress tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ is zero everywhere in the Schwarzschild metric except at the singularity.

Comment: That's confusing. How does it curve spacetime if there is no energy density, mass, etc. Could you give an analogy or explanation of some sort?

Comment: @AtleyAnderson The same thing happens with Newtonian gravity, if you think about it. Imagine you were an astronaut floating in space near the Earth. Earth would generate a gravitational field in the spot you are, even if you are completely in vacuum. There is no energy or mass where you are, but there is a gravitational field nonetheless.

Comment: So could you calculate it at the surface/center of the earth to where there is a stress energy tensor and such??

Comment: the Schwarzschild metric is only defined outside the body. Inside the body the metric is not Schwarzschild and depends on the specific density and pressure profile of the body.

Comment: See the [Interior Schwarzschild metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_Schwarzschild_metric) for the case where the body is made of an incompressible perfect fluid.
I don't think that there is a general solution for the metric.